# How do I calculate $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(\ln 4)^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have hard time solving this expression

> $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(\ln 4)^k}{k!}$$

Please offer some hint

Comment: I've edited your question to format it with Mathjax. Please make sure it says what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f(x) = e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Then $$f(-\ln(4)) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\ln 4)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(\ln 4)^k$$

Comment: 1/4  got it, thanks.